# Lock gummi preview pane to main file

Tags: gummi, live-preview

I got a latex document for which I want to outsource the different chapters

```
+folder
| main.tex
| first.tex
| second.tex
```

I am using gummi as an editor. Now I got the problem or rather inconvenience that as soon as I start editing in another file than `main.tex`, gummi is not showing the current document status in the preview pane anymore as only `main.tex` is an actual completely legal latex document and the other files are only included sub parts and can therefore not be compiled.

```
\begin{document}
\include{./first}
\include{./second}
\end{document}
```

**Can I configure the preview pane in a way that (for a certain project/session) that only a certain file will be compiled and shown in the preview pane?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved the problem indirectly by introducing macros to cover for generating valid latex code in the subfiles.

The `main.tex` file defines `\def\COMPLETE{}` whereas any included file now has in the beginning

```
\ifdefined\COMPLETE
\else
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\input{util} %file containing all the used libraries
\begin{document}
\fi
```

and

```
\ifdefined\COMPLETE
\else
\end{document}
\fi
```

at the end. Therefore if the file is not included in the main, but displayed on its own it still has the necessary code to be valid.